# Context in context of Type Theory

Tags: logic, type-theory, intuitionistic-logic

I am reading a book on  [homotopy type theory](https://homotopytypetheory.org/book/)  or let me better say 'the' book of HoTT.  On page 416, the author
intruduces a judgment that includes the **ctx** (context) formalism. The
judgment

$$(x_1 : A_1, x_2 : A_2, ... , x_n : A_n) \text{ ctx }$$

expresses that each $A_i$ is a type in the context
$x_1 : A_1, x_2 : A_2, ... , x_{i-1} : A_{i-1}$. The next statement
I not understand:

> In particular, therefore, if $\Gamma \vdash a : A $ and
> $\Gamma \text{ ctx } $, then we know that each $A_i$ contains only
> the variables $x_1, ... , x_{i-1}$, and that $a$ and $A$ contain
> only the variables $x_1, ... , x_n $.

As far I not understand this conclusion. By definition the judgement
$\Gamma \vdash a : A $ means just that $a: A$
in context of $\Gamma $. Literally: $a$ has type $A$
under the assumptions listed in $\Gamma$.

The judgment $\Gamma \text{ ctx } $ says literally that the context $\Gamma$
is **well-formed**. As far as I understand it correctly, formally this
is by definition above the statement that if
$\Gamma = (x_1 : A_1, x_2 : A_2, ... , x_n : A_n)$ then that just
means recursively that $A_i$ is a type in the context
$x_1 : A_1, x_2 : A_2, ... , x_{i-1} : A_{i-1}$. Can it be token as
general 'definition' of $\Gamma \text{ ctx } $, am I right?

But then, why from $\Gamma \vdash a : A $ and
$\Gamma \text{ ctx } $  we conclude that $A_i$ contains only
the variables $x_1, ... , x_{i-1}$ and that $a$ and $A$ contain
only the variables $x_1, ... , x_n $? This 'conclusion' isn't clear
for me.

Comment: This deduction is made in the context also of the $\mathsf{Vble}$ rule (page 433), that declares when a variable may be projected out of the context as a term. Since variables must be in the context to be projected, and contexts are built inductively, the statement follows.

Comment: @varkor: Sorry if my considerings are fooling,
I'm just a newbie 
in type theory.
Let abbrev the context $\Gamma := (x_1 : A_1, x_2 : A_2, ... , x_n : A_n)$. 
Then the Vble says just that $\Gamma \text{ ctx }$ implies
$a_i : A_i$, that is exactly what you mean by "projecting out a variable
of the context as a term", right? Futhermore you wrote that
in order to be projected the variables must be in the context.

Comment: What does it mean? That if we assume that $\Gamma \vdash a : A$ 
 $a: A_i$? But why this should imply that $A_i$ contains
$x_1,...x_{i-1}$. Moreover why then $a$ and $A$ "contain" the 
$x_1, ... , x_n$? The word "contain" means for me that type $X$ contains
$x$ iff $x:X$. Is it correct? If yes then the 
conclusion above gives that for every $i$ we have $x_i: a$ and
$x_i: A$. But this not make any sense to me. Do you see the errors in
my resonings?

Comment: The $\mathsf{Vble}$ rule says that if $\Gamma \vdash a : A$, then any variables in $a$ or $A$ must be contained in the context $\Gamma$ (i.e. the variables must be $x_i$ for some $1 \leq i \leq n$). The ctx-ext rule says that we can only form the context $\Gamma$ if $A_i$ is well-typed in context $x_1 : A_1, \ldots, x_{i - 1} : A_{i - 1}$. Again, using the $\mathsf{Vble}$ rule, this means that any variables in $A_i$ must be contained in $x_1 : A_1, \ldots, x_{i - 1} : A_{i - 1}$. We perform this deduction inductively for $1 \leq i \leq n$ to deduce the original statement.

Comment: I would say that there are better introductions to dependent type theory in general: the HoTT Book is not supposed to be a formal introduction to dependent type theory. So if there are parts of the presentation that you find confusing, it might be worth looking to other sources first.

Comment: @varkor: Could you recomend something? I think the root of my confusion
arises from following two points:

In $\Gamma \vdash a : A$ we consider both $a$ AND $A$ (independingly
of 'what means $a: A$) as something "predicate like" things (in model theoretic
sense) that could have certain free variables but the essence of Vble is to assure
that all variables of $a$ as well $A$ are from $\Gamma$, that's the point,
right?

Comment: And secoundly: on the definition of $\Gamma \text{ ctx }$. The book 
inposes as def that this judgment iteratively says that each 
$A_i$ is a type in the context 
$x_1 : A_1, x_2 : A_2, ... , x_{i-1} : A_{i-1}$. Is this the most 
common def of $\Gamma \text{ ctx }$?

Comment: I would recommend against thinking of $a$ and $A$ as existing independently from $\Gamma$. $\mathsf{Vble}$ tells you what variables can form subterms, and they're precisely the ones in the context. The inductive definition of contexts is standard for dependent type theories, yes. [Advanced Topics in Types and Programming Languages](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/attapl/) is a more introductory text for dependent type theories.

Comment: Slowly it becomes clearer except the intuitional point as 'what'
can I think about $a$ and $A$ in context $\Gamma$? You wrote
that Vble says that any variables in $a$ and $A$ my be contained in 
context $\Gamma$. But this suggest then to think about $a$ as well $A$ 
as some object which "has" variables, so a predicate (i.e. a
formula with values in $\{0,1\}$) with additional restriction
on which variables are allowed. So like a appropriate 
"domain" of a function. Is this the correct intuition?

Comment: It's a bit late now, I will try to reflect it next day, thank you for explanations!

Comment: If you made it to page 416 of that book, then congratulations sir (or madam).

Comment: I have to admit that I read this book non chronologically, so 
no I haven't already passed all previous 415 pages (if yes, then probably
I would not ask such basic question). by the way I think the
example here (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3717052/aa-in-gamma?rq=1)
is well choosen to understand to point that confused me. Essentially
the judgment $\Gamma \vdash a : A$ set ups over which parameters
$a$ and $A$ are allowed to be parametrized.

Comment: That is a more explicit
and didactically apropriate expression for $\Gamma \vdash a : A$ woule be
$\Gamma \vdash a(x_1,...,x_n) : A(x_1,...,x_n)$ where
$\Gamma := (x_1 : A_1, x_2 : A_2, ... , x_n : A_n)$. Hope, that I 
understand it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence you are quoting is part of an introduction, meant to give you some intuition behind the formalism of the theory. It does not pretend to give you the meta-theoretical proof that you are looking for: it says "then we know ...", not "this is a proof that ...".

In other words, the formal rules of the theory are *designed* so that in a context $\Gamma$:

- the type $A_i$ may refer only the the variables $x_0, ..., x_{i-1}$
- the terms $a$ and $A$ may refer only to the variables $x_0, ..., x_n$

To have a proof of it, you need to check -all- formal rules of the theory, verify that the rule "Vble" in A.2.2 is the only one to introduce fresh variables, and does it only in a context where this variable is already defined by its type.

Comment: When you say "$a$ or $A$ may refer only to variables $x_0,...,x_n$"
in context of type theory that's exactly then same as to say that
$a= a(x_0,...,x_n)$ respectively $A= A(x_0,...,x_n)$; i.e. in type 
theory it is interpreted in same way as in "classical" math:
as an mathematical object that only depends only on $x_0,...,x_n$, 
that's all, right? Or is the issue here a bit deeper?

Comment: $a$ or $A$ are simply syntaxical expressions in which only the variable $x_0, ..., x_n$ may appear. Possibly $A$ can be $x_3$, and $a$ $x_7$. $a(x_0,...,x_n)$ denotes a function $a$ applied to the parameters $x_0, ..., x_n$, which is a bit different. But you can view $a$ not as the function, but as the result of the application of a function $f_a$ to the parameters $x_0, ..., x_n$.